# Animating tentacles

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify, inverse-kinematics

I'm doing some tests for a character for a videogame I'm making.

[image: Rest pose]

The body is straight from MakeHumans, I imported it with the rig because it would save me the pain of rigging the character myself (and because I'm pretty sure I would not be able to do a better job).
I then cut off the head and modeled those tentacles, which I also rigged and skinned. The effect I'm looking to achieve is something like this:

[image: Closed face]
[image: Test animation]

In the gif it just open and closes but I would also like to achieve a "swirl" effect, basically starting from the pose in the second image, and ending in a specular pose to that while keeping the spherical shape.(Imagine the tentacles sliding over an invisibile sphere)

So to the issue: Right now I just rotated every bone by hand. Is there a way to make this faster? Can IK be set up in such a way to achieve both bending and twisting? Would rigify be of any help? (I'm not sure I can use it since this rig doesn't wasn't made with the metarig)

Edit: I should add that with a basic IK I can get the tentacles to bend, but not to rotate on themselves.

Comment: Rigify is a great rig for the body, but it will not be of any help fro your "head". I would try with an "Action" constraint, where a complicated and handmade animation can be controlled with a single movement of a slider.

Comment: @joshsanfelici do you have a resource or tutorial about action constraints? Never used them before.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zm8JHVpa9Sk, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc8QUoAeCu8

Comment: So that's pretty much interpolating between keyposes manually. Looks promising, thanks!